# java 8 Optional with Map<String, Set<String>>

Tags: java, option-type

I have a  Map<String, Set> getProperties which returns {BUILDING=[a, b, c]}, {NEW_BUILDING=[a, b, c, d, e]}, {OLD_BUILDING=[d, e]}..

I want to switch between BUILDING, NEW_BUILDING and OLD_BUILDING based on the value.

I am trying something like

```
return Optional.ofNullable(properties.get("BUILDING")).map(a -> {
            if(a.contains(code)) {
                return callMethod;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }).get();
```

I want to return based on BUILDING, NEW_BUILDING and OLD_BUIDLING

Comment: Are you trying to access the keys (BUILDING, NEW_BUILDING and OLD_BUIDLING) ?

Comment: Can you post the entire method? Or at least, show us where and what `code` and `callMethod` are?

Comment: What's wrong with `Optional.ofNullable(properties.get(code))` ? Your question doesn't make sense, overall.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I want to return based on the key, if its BUILDING, then return callBuidingMethod, if its NEW_BUILDING then return callNewBuilding and if its OLDBUILDING, then return callOldBuilding.
I want to put switch I believe

Comment: If the `code` is "b", then you have two valid keys in your map to consider: `BUILDING` & `NEW_BUILDING`. Ditto for "d" & "e", each found in *two* sets. How to handle that dual situation? I am voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>> entries = properties.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : entries) {
            Set<String> value = entry.getValue();
            if (value.contains(code)) {
                switch (entry.getKey()) {
                    case "BUILDING":
                        return callBuidingMethod;
                    case "OLD_BUILDING":
                        return callNewBuilding;
                    case "NEW_BUILDING":
                        return callOldBuilding;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When looking for a `code` of "a", "b", or "c", your solution arbitrarily chooses `BUILDING` case while the `NEW_BUILDING` case is also valid yet goes ignored. Similarly for "d" & "e", both `NEW_BUILDING` & `OLD_BUILDING` are valid, yet you use only one.